Ишу программу для покадровой анимации SVG с полноценным CSS
Вопрос:
Существует ли приложение которое работает полноценно с svg полностью поддерживает современный css и способно в анимацию с выводом какого-то формата данных манипуляций с картинкой ?.
Описание:
Игра. Элементы игры сделаны на svg
По причине:

легко кастомизируются js и css
лёгкий вес.
возможность запихать логику картинки в саму картинку .
качество картинки

Svg содержит все вариации элементов кастомизации и собирает в итоговый элемент по параметрам и безумно мало весит
Нужна анимация .сделал свою систему анимации по кадрам(простые варианты трансформации нужных частей ).все работает .но что-то я замотался .....N-моделей * N-частей_модели * N-количества-трансформаций * N-кадров .....
(Код старый .сейчас переделал на генераторы но это особо не меняет формата записи кадра ....)

И каждый раз сохранять и смотреть что вышло при изменении малейшего числа
Попытки :
Не нашел не одного нормального редактора от слова совсем

Инскейп - болт клал на css (переменные ало и вечно вылетает при их редактировании)а анимации там не поделаешь .(Не удобно доставать положения каждого элемента и не видно всю анимацию)

Adobe Edge Animate -
оказался очень не удобным в плане построения анимации .но он максимально близок.
Основная проблема это в том как редактировать анимации
и их просматривать
а также назначать дубли,зациливать и тд .все это очень не удобно.и ручками перекладывать все кадры

Блендер - тоже не удобно выводить информацию
Css нет от слова совсем

Фигма - как понял тоже в css на вы .не хрена нету функционала .только заготовленные настройки .


В других редакторах тоже про сss не знают
А без этого не возможно записать какие-то моменты анимаций для управления ими из js и сложные связи элементов в анимации
Было много проверено но я позже дополню и уточню список.пока просто забыл.
Предположительное решение:
По-сути все основное я уже написал .осталось только редактор простенький хотя бы за пилить .

с деревом элементов
манипуляторами
и шкалой кадров
выводом кода .

Но это прилично займет времени .
Я очень надеюсь что существует полноценный редактор svg точечный под веб ,а не иллюстратор который клал болт на спецификацию svg реализуя куча того что не работает в вебе ) и я просто что-то не знаю или где-то не увидел и не понял.
